Jenkins scripted pipeline with eacstasktemplate picking old version of task definition
We are using both scripted and declarative jenkins pipeline and using dynamic ecs agent for slave.
Following is the configuration :
ecsTaskTemplate(
    inheritFrom: dynamiclabelNp
    overrides: [],   
    taskDefinitionOverride: "arn:aws:redacted:redacted:task-definition/td:9"
) {
  node(dynamiclabelNp) {
    stage("I dunno why you say goodbye"){
      sh 'echo hello'
    }
  }
}

And for declarative pipeline:
pipeline {
  agent none

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
        agent {
            ecs {
                inheritFrom dynamiclabelNp,
overrides: [],   
        taskDefinitionOverride: "arn:aws:redacted:redacted:task-definition/td:9"          
            }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'echo hello'
        }
    }
  }
}

Now for declarative pipeline the node is coming up with a random name and picking the above task definition. But for scripted it is showing all node in label "dynamic-agent-test" is offline and if I see the logs it shows that task definition (arn:aws:redacted:redacted:task-definition/td:7) does not exist, which is a old task definition.
How to resolve this for scripted pipeline.

What's dynamiclabelNp? Where do you define it, what value do you assign?
